# How to get a range in a google sheets onEdit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to write a simple on Edit function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = parseInt(e.range.getRow())
    if(row > 19){
      //This doesn't work because its reading a strig instead of a number.  Who knows why
      var rng = e.source.getRange(21,1,1,6)//.getValues()[0].join('').length
      e.source.toast(rng.getValue())
    
    if (length===0){
      e.source.getRange(row,8).setBackground('white')
    } else {
      e.source.getRange(row,8).setBackground('red')
    }
    
  }  
}
```

And I got this error:

> Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.

[image]

I actually wanted to do this:

```
var rng = e.source.getRange(row,1,1,6).getValues()[0].join('').length
```

But even the number 21 is now a string.  It's like its own bizarro world where some numbers are strings. I even did a paranoid parseInt.  It's a whole new world.

I had this appear at the top of the question once.  I don't have much in the way of SO ettiquette or practice, but I saw this on the question this morning.
[image]

and I have to tell you none of those answers is the remedy.  The critical qualifier in the question is the appearance of the symptom on the onEdit trigger and knowing that the event object e.source isn't a worksheet, it's some other object.  That's why it's coercing.  Also, it's odd that javascript can coerce, given how its loosely typed and all.  Know the second, it's now clear I had the wrong object.  That's the answer to the question.  Otherwise, getRange.  Not too difficult.  Two different getRanges, one on an undocumented object.  Much harder to divine.

Comment: [Edit] to quote error as text as it'll help others in searching for the error. The reason the first parameter is a string is because there is a attempt by JavaScript engine to match the actual function call signature: `getRange(string)`. It converts `21` to string, but it doesn't know what to do with the rest of the parameters( numbers as there is no method signature that match the call (string, number,number,number)).

Comment: I figured it out, it's e.range.getSheet().getRange(row,1,1,6)